# SplashScreenImage as Background: little jump at the start?

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, splash-screen

I've the same image as SplashScreenImage and as background, the effect is nice but at the start, after the loading, my image slides a bit on the top..

It's pretty visible (and disturbing) as effect, because the image is the same..

I'm using the ApplicationBar (all visible), don't know if it's a problem.
I've setted the background image as "Uniform to fill" (tried all btw) in my LayoutRoot, I've a Pivot control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really the ApplicationBar, if you set it opacity to something like "0.99" you problem should go away.

But the best result may be just by having a second image, with 480x728 (the ApplicationBar is 72px height, so 800 - 72 = 728)